# AMD Graphics Driver issue

Tags: drivers, 18.04, 64-bit, radeon, amd-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to work on the Odin Project. I was going through the system logs and found out that my graphics card isn't being used (the AMD one).

Here's the error:

```
05:31:02 kernel: [drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed
05:31:02 kernel: [drm:si_dpm_enable [radeon]] *ERROR* si_init_smc_table failed
05:31:02 kernel: [drm:si_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* si startup failed on resume
05:31:02 kernel: [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xFFFFFFFF)
05:30:59 kernel: [drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed
05:30:59 kernel: [drm:si_dpm_enable [radeon]] *ERROR* si_init_smc_table failed
05:30:59 kernel: [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 6860 (len 94, WS 12, PS 8) @ 0x6868
05:30:59 kernel: [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
05:19:36 kernel: [drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed
05:19:36 kernel: [drm:si_dpm_enable [radeon]] *ERROR* si_init_smc_table failed
05:19:36 kernel: [drm:si_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* si startup failed on resume
05:19:36 kernel: [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xFFFFFFFF)
05:19:34 kernel: [drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed
05:19:34 kernel: [drm:si_dpm_enable [radeon]] *ERROR* si_init_smc_table failed
05:19:34 kernel: [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 6860 (len 94, WS 12, PS 8) @ 0x6868
05:19:34 kernel: [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
03:48:10 kernel: [drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed
03:48:10 kernel: [drm:si_dpm_enable [radeon]] *ERROR* si_init_smc_table failed
03:48:10 kernel: [drm:si_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* si startup failed on resume
03:48:10 kernel: [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xFFFFFFFF)
03:48:08 kernel: [drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed
03:48:08 kernel: [drm:si_dpm_enable [radeon]] *ERROR* si_init_smc_table failed
03:48:07 kernel: [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 6860 (len 94, WS 12, PS 8) @ 0x6868
03:48:07 kernel: [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
```

After running lspci command:

```
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE 
[Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
```

The screen is a bit glitchy at times while playing 720p mp4 video on the default player. Also while booting some errors are displayed before the Ubuntu loading screen, don't know what that's about, probably the AMD.

How can I debug/fix this?